# Syntax error at the end of input when all brackets match

Tags: c, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I realize this concern is almost always due to a simple mistype, but I can't for the life of me find the cause of this error. I've gone through the brackets multiple times and have checked if I'm missing any, but see nothing wrong. Excusing the disgusting way in which I initialized an array, what is wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>

#define BufferLength 100
#define SERVPORT 5011

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  int sd, sd2, rc, length = sizeof(int);
  int totalcnt = 0, on = 1;
  char temp;
  char buffer[BufferLength];
  char init[10];
  struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
  struct sockaddr_in their_addr;
  fd_set read_fd;
  struct timeval timeout;
  timeout.tv_sec = 60;
  timeout.tv_usec = 0;
  int new_sd;
  int nfds = 1; int len;
//..........................SOCKET SETUP..............................................||

  if((sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)    
  {   
      perror("Socket error");     
      exit (-1); 
  }

  if((rc = setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&on, sizeof(on))) < 0)
  {   
      perror("socket setup error"); 
      close(sd); 
      exit (-1); 
  }

  memset(&serveraddr, 0x00, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
  serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serveraddr.sin_port = htons(SERVPORT);
  serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

  printf("Using %s, listening at %d\n", inet_ntoa(serveraddr.sin_addr), SERVPORT);


//............................BINDING...............................................|| 

  if((rc = bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr))) < 0)
  {   
      perror("server binding error");    
      close(sd);    
      exit(-1);    
  }


//............................LISTENING.............................................||

  if((rc = listen(sd, 8)) < 0)               
  {    perror("listen error"); close(sd);    exit (-1);}
  else
       printf("Ready for up to eight connections...\n");

  int sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);


//............................ACCEPTING..............................................||

  if((sd2 = accept(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size)) < 0)
  {    perror("Server-accept() error");   close(sd);    exit (-1);  }

  printf("Got connection from the accursed client: %s\n", inet_ntoa(their_addr.sin_addr));

  FD_ZERO(&read_fd);
  FD_SET(sd2, &read_fd);

//..................................POLL STUFF.......................................||

  int i,n;
  int m = 0;
  char ** init0 = (char**)malloc(9);
  for( m; m<10; m+=1)
       init0[m] = (char*)malloc(100);
  char * left = (char*)malloc(100);
  char * enter = (char*)malloc(100);
  char ** Tinit0 = (char**)malloc(9);
  for(m = 0; m<10; m+=1)
      Tinit0[m] = (char*)malloc(100);

  memset(left,0,100);
  for(m = 0; m<10; m+=1)
     memset(Tinit0[m],0,100);
  for(m = 0; m<10; m+=1)
    memset(init0[m],0,100);
  memset(enter, 0, 100);
  strcpy(enter,"Entered:_  ");
  strcpy(left,"Left: ");

  struct pollfd ufds[9];
  ufds[0].fd = sd;    
  ufds[0].events = POLLIN; 
  ufds[1].fd = sd2;
  ufds[1].events = POLLOUT;
  ufds[2].fd = sd2;
  ufds[2].events = POLLOUT;
  ufds[3].fd = sd2;
  ufds[3].events = POLLOUT;
  ufds[4].fd = sd2;
  ufds[4].events = POLLOUT;
  ufds[5].fd = sd2;
  ufds[5].events = POLLOUT;
  ufds[6].fd = sd2;
  ufds[6].events = POLLOUT;
  ufds[7].fd = sd2;
  ufds[7].events = POLLOUT;
  ufds[8].fd = sd2;
  ufds[8].events = POLLOUT;

  //timeout = (6000);

  n = poll(ufds, 9, 40000);
  do{
      for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
      {
         if(ufds[i].revents == 0)
             continue;

         if (ufds[i].fd == sd)
         {
             do
             {
                 new_sd = accept(sd2, NULL, NULL);
                 ufds[nfds].fd = new_sd;
                 ufds[nfds].events = POLLIN;
                 nfds++;
              } while (new_sd != -1);
          }
          else 
          { 
             do
             {
                 rc = recv(ufds[i].fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
                 len =rc;
                 if(strcmp(init0[i],"") == 0)                          // IF INITAL HAS NOT BEEN SET UP
                 {                                                  // (DURING FIRST CONNECTION FROM CLIENT)
                     if((rc == 1) && (FD_ISSET(sd2, &read_fd)))
                     {
                        printf("initial from client is: %s\n",buffer);
                        strcpy(init0[i],buffer);
                        printf("init0 is: %s\n", init0[i]); Tinit0[i] = init0[0];
                      }
                     strcat(enter, init0[i]); 
                     printf("string enter is: %s , about to try write enter\n",enter);
                     for(m = 1; m <9; m+=1) 
                         rc = send(ufds[m].fd, enter, 20, 0);
                 } 
                 strcat(Tinit0[i],"__");
                 for(m = 1; m <9; m+=1)
                      rc = send(ufds[m].fd, Tinit0[i], 100, 0);       
                 if(rc==0)
                 {
                     strcat(left, init0[i]);
                     printf("%s\n",left);
                     for(m = 1; m <9; m+=1)
                         rc = send(ufds[m].fd, left, 100, 0);
                 }
             } while(1==1);
           } //end of else
       } //end of for
   } //end of do 

}
```

Comment: GCC reports: `178:1: error: expected ‘while’ before ‘}’ token`

Comment: @Rufflewind: It also warns about incorrect `printf` format strings on lines 50 and 78.

Comment: @iharob: I've deleted my comment, and I'll delete this one in a moment. Feel free to delete your "Wow sorry" comment.

Comment: Lets start with this code, when run through the compiler produces a long long array of warning messages.  Perhaps if you fixed those warnings, the syntax error would be easily visible.

Comment: the code is missing the needed prototypes for the sub functions

Comment: the code fails to check the returned value from malloc() to assure the operation was successful and fails to free() the malloc'd areas.  Resulting in numerous memory leaks.

Comment: the 'do' loop, immediately after: n = poll(ufds, 9, 40000); is missing the terminating 'wile( ... );' after the closing brace.  note: this problem took me ~5 minutes to find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `do {} while()` loop is simply missing the `while` keyword.

Comment: I'm an utter fool. Thank you.